# Django query to get all record where length of bigint field is less than 10

Tags: orm, django-orm

i have one model userprofile in my django project and mobile_number is one for the modelfiled in that model. i want to get all the userprofiles where length of mobile_number is less than 10.
i know the solution when field is CharField

```
qs = UserProfile.objects.annotate(text_len=Length('mobile_number')).filter(text_len__lt=10)
```

but here mobile_number is BigIntegerField.
thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh i did it using regex..Thanks

```
qs = UserProfile.objects.filter(mobile_number__regex = r'^\d{1,9}$')
```